# CakePHPで異なるDB間でアソシエーションを組む方法

Tags: php, cakephp

バージョンはCakePHP2.4.6です。
DBはMySQLを使用しています。

異なるDB間でアソシエーションを組むにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？
同一DB内で試すと正しい結果が取得できているのですが、
異なるDBにすると望んだ結果が得られません。

DB・tableは下記のようになっています。

database.php

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '192.168.*.***',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'customer_db',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
public $company_db= array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '192.168.*.***',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'company_db',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

DB・Table構造

```
DB：customer_db
CREATE TABLE customer (
　id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
　company_code INT NOT NULL,
　customer_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
　PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

DB：company_db
CREATE TABLE company (
　id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
　company_code INT NOT NULL,
　company_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
　PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO customer (company_code, customer_type) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C');

INSERT INTO company (company_code, company_name) VALUES
(1, 'ああああ株式会社'),
(2, '株式会社いいいい'),
(3, 'うううう株式会社');
```

これを下記のようにアソシエーションしています。

コントローラー

```
<?php
class CustomerController extends AppController {

  public $uses = array('Customer', 'Company');

    public function index() {
      $data = $this->Customer->find('all', array('limit' => 3));
      $this->set('customer', $data);
    }

}
```

モデル

```
//Customer.php
<?php

class Customer extends AppModel {

  public $name = 'Customer';
  public $useDbConfig = "default";
  public $useTable = "customer";

  public $belongsTo = array(
      'Company' => array(
          'className' => 'Company',
          'fields' => array('company_code', 'company_name'),
          'conditions' => array('Customer.company_code = Company.company_code')
      )
  );
}

//Company.php
<?php

class Company extends AppModel {

  public $name = 'Company';
  public $useDbConfig = "company_db";
  public $useTable = "company";

}
```

これを実行すると下記のような結果が出力されます。

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'company_code' => '1',
            'customer_type' => 'A'
        ),
        'Company' => array(
            'company_code' => '1',
            'company_name' => 'ああああ株式会社'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'company_code' => '2',
            'customer_type' => 'B'
        ),
        'Company' => array(
            'company_code' => '1',
            'company_name' => 'ああああ株式会社'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'company_code' => '3',
            'customer_type' => 'C'
        ),
        'Company' => array(
            'company_code' => '1',
            'company_name' => 'ああああ株式会社'
        )
    )
)
```

Customer側は全データ正しく取得できているのですが、
Company側が全て最初の1レコードしか取得できません。
そこでSQLのログを確認したところ下記のようなSQL文が発行されていました。

```
SELECT `Customer`.`id`, `Customer`.`company_code`, `Customer`.`customer_type` FROM `customer_db`.`customer` AS `Customer` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 3
SELECT `Company`.`company_code`, `Company`.`company_name` FROM `company_db`.`company` AS `Company` WHERE 1 = 1
SELECT `Company`.`company_code`, `Company`.`company_name` FROM `company_db`.`company` AS `Company` WHERE 1 = 1
SELECT `Company`.`company_code`, `Company`.`company_name` FROM `company_db`.`company` AS `Company` WHERE 1 = 1
```

なぜJOINされないのかが調べてもわかりませんでした。
2つのテーブルを同一DB内に置いた場合は正しくJOINされていました。
異なるDB間でのJOINは不可能なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

異なるDBは別のデータソースと認識されるので、JOINできません。

この場合、リレーションを設定するのではなく、`Customer::afterFind()`を実装して、そこで`Company`モデルからデータを取得、紐付けします。

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    $Company = ClassRegistry::init('Company');
    if (Hash::numeric(array_keys($results))) {
        // $results = [ 0 => ['Customer' => ...], 1 => ['Customer' => ...], ]
        $results = array_map(function ($record) use ($Company) {
            $conditions = [ /* 取得条件 */ ];
            $data = $Company->find('first', compact('conditions'));
            $record = Hash::merge($record, $data);
            return $record;
        }, $results);
    } else {
        // $results = ['Customer' => ...]
        $conditions = [ /* 取得条件 */ ];
        $data = $Company->find('first', compact('conditions'));
        $results = Hash::merge($results, $data);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

なお、このコードでは複数のCustomerが帰ってくる場合は、ひとつひとつCompanyを取得するのでかなり効率が悪いです。
できれば、必要なCompanyを一括で取得した後に紐付けを行った方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
JOINすることばかり考えてafterFindを使うことなんて思いもしませんでした。
>必要なCompanyを一括で取得した後に紐付けを行った方がよいかもしれません。
これでやってみます。
ありがとうございます。